# If $a,b,c(a,b,c\in\mathbb{R} )$ satisfy $b^2-4ac<0$ then equation $f(x)=0$ has complex root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: show that ($n>2, n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+ax^2+bx+c, ~(a_i\in\mathbb{R}(i=3,4,\cdots,n),a_n\neq
 0) $

If $a,b,c(a,b,c\in\mathbb{R} )$ satisfy $b^2-4ac<0$ then equation $f(x)=0$ has complex root

Comment: You mean: a root which is not real, I guess?

Comment: This is a nice question as of i am concerned... do you mind to tell what topics can anybody use to solve this?

Comment: This is either not true (if you mean a non-real root) or follows trivially from the fundamental theorem of algebra (if you just mean any complex root; the restrictions on $a, b, c$ are not needed). Is this really the question you want to ask?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that $f(x)=0$ must a have a complex root that **isn't real**, then this is not true. Look at the polynomial
$$
f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1.
$$

Here $b^2 - 4ac = 3^2 - 4\cdot 3 \cdot 1 = (-3) < 0$, but the only complex root of $f$ is $x_0 = -1$ (with multiplicity $3$), which is real.

If you mean that $f(x)=0$ must simply have a complex root, then this is true because $a_n \neq 0$ by the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: I mean that $f(x)=0$ must simply have a complex root

Comment: If you want a proof that doesn't use the fundamental theorem of algebra, say so. Otherwise people will not try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be helped because it is wrong. Indeed, just take the two examples
of polynomials with all their roots being real
$$
(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)=x^3-7x+6=0,\quad b^2-4ac=49>0,
$$
$$                             
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0,\quad b^2-4ac=-23<0,
$$
despite the sign of the discriminant $b^2-4ac$.

Comment: How does this follow? It seems to me your examples just show the contrapositive of the statement, not disprove it, but it's late, I could be wrong.